Why was Toulour watching Ocean team before Benedict hired him?
In Ocean's Thirteen, Ocean's team make a deal with Benedict to get the money for the drill they needed.
At the end, in the scene on a rooftop  we see Toulour trying to steal the diamonds from them for Benedict (which were fake diamonds).
Later there is hinted that Benedict hired Toulour to watch over them,but what's bothering me is that Toulour was seen watching over Ocean's gang in the hotel, long before Benedict hired him.
It seems that he was doing it for no reason, did I miss something or is it a plot hole?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I haven't watched Ocean's Thirteen in a long time, but Danny and his team outran Toulour in Ocean's Twelve. He pretty much got humiliated and knowing how ego he has, it is enough of a reason for him to try to get revenge.
